# how to print hex representation of a data type correctly?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, let's say I want to print a short int as:

```
short s = 0xbeef;
printf("This is 0x%x", s);
```

the output is `0xffffbeef`

and it looks like `short` has four bytes, but actually `short` only has two bytes, so why `%x` cannot print it properly? and if it has a rule that a minimum 4 bytes representation is required then why the output  is `0xffffbeef` rather than `0x0000beef`?

Comment: the size of the data type and its address in ram is somehow diffrent. the address is 4 (in your case) bytes aligned. do you aware of memory alignement?
the address tells the start of the variable not the size.

Comment: Another problem is that the value you're putting in your short, 0xbeef = 48879, is too large for a signed short (which can only represent -32768 to +32767). Hence the value you actually have is -16657. When promoted to 32-bits this gets sign-extended to the 32-bit representation of -16657, which is 0xffffbeef.

Comment: @B.Nadolson: That is incorrect. Per C 2018 6.4.4.1, `0xbeef` is an `int` with value 48879. When `short s` is initialized with `0xbeef`, 48879 is converted to `short`. Given that `short` is 16 bits, this conversion is implementation-defined, per C 2018 6.3.1.3. If the implementation uses two’s complement and wraps during the conversion, the result is indeed −16657. Also, the text you quote as “part of the C specification” does not appear in the C standard.

Comment: @Rup: Is `%hf` a typo? `f` is for floating-point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oops, yes, I meant %hx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and it looks like short has four bytes, but actually short only has
>   two bytes, so why %x cannot print it properly?

No it is not the reason. The signed value of the `s` is -16657. When you pass it to the printf it is being promoted to the `int`. The promoted value has 32bits representation of `0xffffbeef` ([Two's_complement format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). That is the reason why you see this number as you wanted to output unsigned integer not unsigned short.  https://godbolt.org/z/qKwzUv

Use the correct format and everything will be fine...

Good people from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf created this lovely table:

now check the row where the x(and X) format is decribed. Find the unsigned short integer and you find it in the column `h`. So the format is `%hx` or `%hX`

[image]
https://godbolt.org/z/wQCa9p

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, but pass why when it to the printf it is being promoted to the int? and what does "h" stand for as length modifier?

Comment: Because %x is the format specifier for an int in hexadecimal representation. Thus beeing 32-bit in most compiler but this again depend from on to another compiler

Comment: @BalGu: `%x` is a conversion specification for an `unsigned int`, not for an `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah the edit button dissapered too fast. My bad. But thanks for pointing it out anyway.